# Installing Spring Boot Application on Linux System

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot

Enviroment:

- spring boot 1.5.2
- linux redhat

I have used the Spring Docu:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

And so i created a symbolic link (*etc/init.d/myService*). And everythink works fine. I can controll  my service via:
*sudo service myService start|stop|staus*

But unfortunately i am not allowed to put a symbolic link within /etc/init.d

I have tried to put a script *myService* within */etc/init.d* and this script contains only one row:

*/work/springBoot/myService.jar*

But now when i enter

*sudo service myService status*

The spring boot application starts. And not the status is displayed. So what can i do?

Comment: I think you have to follow the sysvinit convention. I’m guessing your red hat is not using systemd

Comment: systemd is not a option - what do you mean with "follow the sysvinit convention"

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 345 20 80
SPRING_BOOT_JAR=myService-0.1.1.jar
SPRING_BOOT_DIR=/work/springboot/myService
EXECUTABLE=$SPRING_BOOT_DIR/$SPRING_BOOT_JAR

export OUT_LOG="$SPRING_BOOT_DIR/out.log"
export MODE="service"

start() {

echo "Start was called for " + $EXECUTABLE
nohup $SPRING_BOOT_DIR/$SPRING_BOOT_JAR start > $OUT_LOG 2>&1 &

}

stop() {

echo "Stop was called for " + $EXECUTABLE
$SPRING_BOOT_DIR/$SPRING_BOOT_JAR stop

}

status() {

echo "Status was called for " + $EXECUTABLE
$SPRING_BOOT_DIR/$SPRING_BOOT_JAR "status"

}

case "$1" in

start)
    start
    ;;
stop)
    stop
    ;;
status)
    status
    ;;
*)
    echo "Please use start|stop|status"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit
```

The trick was

```
export MODE="service"
```